# Unable to connect to tor kali-rolling repo

Tags: kali-linux, http, tor

I've been stuck on this for a while and have tried many approaches with no success. When I try to install tor on Kali I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  tor-geoipdb torsocks
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster torbrowser-launcher tor-arm apparmor-utils obfsproxy obfs4proxy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tor tor-geoipdb torsocks
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove on and 0 not upgraded
Need to get 2,286 kb of archives
After this operation, 8,641kb of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y *** obviously I input this!***
Err:1 http://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tor amd64 0.2.7.6-1
  Unable to connect to :http:
Err:2 http://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 torsocks amd64 2.1.0-2
  Unable to connect to :http:
Err:3 http://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tor-geo amd64 2.1.0-2
  Unable to connect to :http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali/pool/main/t/tor/tor_0.2.7.6-1_amd64.deb Unable to connect to :http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali/pool/main/t/torsocks/torsocks_2.1.0-2_amd64.deb Unable to connect to :http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali/pool/main/t/tor/tor--geoipdb_0.2.7.6-1_all.deb Unable to connect to :http:

E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

My sources.list has the following two lines in it:

```
deb http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Is this an issue on Kali's end? I can ping Kali fine, and if I run apt-get update most things come down except these packages. If I actually go to the ftp in the browser I can see the files but for some reason they aren't being seen through the terminal. I'm out of ideas, help will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Please show the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Hi Jiggly, thanks for coming back to me. I've played around with that file based on some research and it now has two lines in it:                                        deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free                      #deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib                    I've tried every iteration of suggestions on SE, also tried older version of sana from the Kali website however as you can see I've now reverted just to the default that Kali says to use

Comment: "unable to handle the media swap" comes from the days when packages would be installed from physical media (CD-ROM).  Do you have any files under `/etc/apt/source.list.d/` ?

Comment: I've opened that folder and there's nothing in it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: When I try `apt-get update` I'm seeing `The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file`. It then goes on to 404 not found for the binary-amd64 packages. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner, don't know much in depth about the issue. I, though, wasted my two whole days searching on internet about same problem: "kali rolling repository is not updating but could ping yahoo.com." Nothing worked. Then I switched from my public hostel Wi-Fi to paid mobile internet hotspot, re-tried the following command:

```
apt-get update
```

and it worked perfectetly. If U are using some school or public Wi-Fi, it maybe restricting or blocking your hits. If nothing else has worked, try SWITCHING your internet connections or use VPN. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your sources list is wrong.

You have `deb http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

It should be `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is the solution

Add the following lines to your etc/apt/source.list file

```
deb ftp://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

STEPS:

1. Open File Manager
2. Go to `Other Locations`
3. Open `Computer`
4. Open `etc`
5. Open `apt`
6. Right click and select `Open in Terminal`
7. In the terminal type the following

   ```
   nano source.list
   ```
8. Then delete all the contents of it and Copy the following and paste in the Windows.

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   deb ftp://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
   ```
9. Press <kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
10. Press <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd>
11. Open a new Terminal and type

    ```
    apt-get update
    ```

    or

    ```
    sudo apt-get update
    ```

Hope it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update the repos sources with the following then `apt-get clean` and then `apt-get update`

```
deb ftp://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and edit `sources.list` and add this line :

```
deb ftp://ftp.ne.jp/Linux/packages/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

and then do `apt-get update`.